# Why is my tuple for time breakpoints [m, m+1] not working?

Tags: cplex, opl

I hope that somebody can help me. I modeled a vehicle routing problem with time windows and outsourcing option, in addition I want to make the model time dependent. To do this I made some time zones that need to be connected

```
 {<0,120>,<120,600>,<600,720>,<720,1400>}.
```

These time zones are needed because in every timezone the vehicle drives a different speed.

The problem I encounter is when I model the constraint where the departure time of vehicle `k` at customer `i`

```
a[i][k]
```

needs to be associated with the correct time zone. 
Once I initialize the time zones the model gives me a incorrect solution.

```
 tuple timezone{
 int m;
 int mend;
 };

{timezone} timezones = {<0,120>,<120,600>,<600,720>,<720,1400>};

forall (i in N, k in K, m in timezones)
  a[i][k] <=   m.mend * sum (j in N) G[i][j][k][m]; 

forall (i in N, k in K, m in timezones)
  a[i][k] >=   m.m * sum (j in N) G[i][j][k][m];
```

Where `G[i][j][k][m]` is a boolean variable telling if an arc is traversed with vehicle `k` in timezone `m`. And `m.m` is the start of a time zone and `m.mend` is the end of a time zone.

The tuple does work when I only state there is one timezone, as

```
{timezone} timezones = {<0,900>};
```

But only for the first constraint

```
a[i][k] >=   m.m * sum (j in N) G[i][j][k][m];
```

When I add this constraint to the model:

```
a[i][k] >=   m.m * sum (j in N) G[i][j][k][m];
```

The model doesn't work anymore

I expect that some of the customers i are outsourced and some are delivered with the private fleet. Once I try to work with the time zones, the model says directly that every customer is outsourced.

Does somebody know what is wrong with the tuple? Because I think the constraint itself is quite basic and should work.

Comment: This is not enough data to answer your question. We probably have to see the full model and full data. Or at least you should create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Moreover, in your post the constraint after "When I add this constraint to the model" is the same as the previous one. Copy-paste error?
In order to debug things like that it is a good idea to look at the solution you get. Then fix a variable you think is incorrect to the value you think is correct. Then solve again and compare the two solutions.

Comment: Also in your case, what happens at time 120, for example? That belongs to two timezones. Are things well-defined at these points?